# How to work arround php notice raised incorrecty when posting a string that begins with an @?

Tags: php, post, curl, encoding

I want to perform a post request using PHP and Curl.
This is how I set my post parameters:

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,array('name'=> $name));
```

When the String in $name happens to contain an @ character at the beginning I get the following error.

> [8192] curl_setopt(): The usage of the @filename API for file
>   uploading is deprecated. Please use the CURLFile class instead on line
>   ** in file ***

I don't want to send any file, I just want to post the string. How can I do that? Need I to encode it?

Is this a Bug? I temporary worked around the issue by passing my post data using a string that is prepared using http_build_query.

This causes Curl to send the data application/x-www-form-urlencoded which is ok for now, but what if it was not? How need I pass the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you receive that message it means you are using `PHP 5.5` (this is the version when the [`CURLFile`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile.php) class was introduced).

On the same version they introduced the [`curl option`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) `CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD` (which has the default value `FALSE` on PHP 5.5).

All you have to do is to add:

```
curl_setopt(CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, TRUE);
```

and the error should vanish.

**An excerpt from the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php):**

> **`CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD`**
>
> `TRUE` to disable support for the `@` prefix for uploading files in `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`, which means that values starting with `@` can be safely passed as fields. [`CURLFile`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile.php) may be used for uploads instead.
>
> Added in PHP 5.5.0 with `FALSE` as the default value. PHP 5.6.0 changes the default value to `TRUE`.